# Sending e-mails to users in specific roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a custom membership provider based on SimpleMembership together with ASP.NET's DefaultRoleProvider. I want to send an e-mail to the site administrators every time a new item is added to the database.

This is the model for users:

```
public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the following code to list the UserName of each user in the Administrator role into a ViewData and it works fine:

```
string userRoles = string.Concat(Roles.GetUsersInRole("Administrator"));
ViewData.Add("UserRoles", userRoles);
```

How can I output the Email field instead of the UserName into a ViewBag and return them into a class called UserMailer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every username you'll have to retrieve a user object from membership and use email from user object.

MembershipProvider has method `GetUser(string username, bool UpdateLastSeenTimestamp)`. This gives you back an object `MembershipUser` that has `Email` property.

So for every username that you get back from role provider you'll need to call that method:

```
// pseudocode, not tested
var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Administrator");
var users = new List<MembershipUser>();
var emails = new List<String>();
foreach(var username in usernames){
    var user = MembershipProvider.GetUser(username, false);
    users.Add(user);
    emails.Add(user.Email);
}
```

so `users` contain list of user objects - if you need them somewhere. And `emails` will contain list of emails for these users.

p.s. Don' use `ViewData` to pass emails to your components (Mailer). `ViewData` is only meant to pass information to/from view, not between your classes.

Comment: Thanks for that example. Certainly has pointed me in the right direction. The only exception is that I'm using a custom membership provider linked to my own table. I will need to override the `GetUser` method to load the e-mail property from the `DatabaseContext`.

Comment: if your user objects are in database, why don't you get that directly from the DB?

Comment: I've changed it to fetch from the database directly. When I try to output the `emails` list in a view, I see `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]`. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you are trying to execute `.ToString()` on `List<String>`. And List does not have a suitable override to produce a string. You need to iterate through the list and output strings: `@foreach(var email in emailsList){ @email}`.

Comment: Since the view is not strongly typed, I used `@foreach (var email in (List<String>)ViewData["Emails"]){ @email }` instead and it works. One last thing, how can I then send that `ViewData` to the `UserMailer` class?

Comment: Now this is a whole new different question. Why don't you follow the tutorial instructions on MvcMailer github puage, or http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/sending-emails-using-mvcmailer . And better to use strongly typed view, instead of ViewData.

Comment: Understood, I will visit those links. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.